# Copy input, textarea data from one window to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create a copy paste functionality of textarea and input data from one table to same table on another window excluding the first tds. When I press Ctl+c it copies, and in another tab same browser Ctrl+ v pastes

Winow tab 1 copy data from this

```
<tr>
  <td class="tbody_data side">Alkalinity/Acidity</td>
  <td class="tbody_data" style="padding: 0px;">
    <textarea class="det_st form-control" style="border:none; "></textarea>
  </td>
  <td class="tbody_data" style="padding: 0px;">
    <textarea class="det_st form-control" style="border:none;"></textarea>
  </td>
  <td class="tbody_data" style="padding: 0px;">
    <textarea class="det_st form-control" style="border:none;"></textarea>
  </td>
  <td class="tbody_data" style="padding: 0px;">
    <textarea class="det_st form-control" style="border:none;"></textarea>
  </td>
  <td class="tbody_data side" style="padding: 25px;  width:50px;">
    <select class="select" style="border:none; width:145px;">
      <option value="COMPLIES">COMPLIES</option>
      <option value="DOES NOT COMPLY">DOES NOT COMPLY</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Paste to this on window 2

```
<tr>
  <td class="tbody_data side">Microbiology</td>
  <td class="tbody_data" style="padding: 0px;">
    <textarea class="det_st form-control" style="border:none; "></textarea>
  </td>
  <td class="tbody_data" style="padding: 0px;">
    <textarea class="det_st form-control" style="border:none;"></textarea>
  </td>
  <td class="tbody_data" style="padding: 0px;">
    <textarea class="det_st form-control" style="border:none;"></textarea>
  </td>
  <td class="tbody_data" style="padding: 0px;">
    <textarea class="det_st form-control" style="border:none;"></textarea>
  </td>
  <td class="tbody_data side" style="padding: 25px;  width:50px;">
    <select class="select" style="border:none; width:145px;">
      <option value="COMPLIES">COMPLIES</option>
      <option value="DOES NOT COMPLY">DOES NOT COMPLY</option>
    </select>

  </td>
</tr>
```

Suggestions

Comment: How it should work?

You want this on ctrl + c / ctrl + v keys?

Comment: Yes Andrzej, exactly

Answer (score 0):

in another BROWSER TAB? well, I can only imagine using localstorage.

Add an id or a unique class to the inputs, then grab the val of each:

```
var input1 = $("#idOfInput1").val();
var input2 = $("#idOfInput2").val();
...

localStorage["input1"] = input1;
localStorage["input2"] = input2;
```

create a button "save", and make the previous code (completed by you) inside the click event of the button.

On the other window, get a "load" button. on the on click event, read the content of the localsorage items, and load them into your table, which needs to have ids or classes.

```
$("#loadbutton").on("click",function(){
   $("#contentinput1").text(localStorage["input1"]);
   $("#contentinput2").text(localStorage["input2"]);
   $("#contentinput3").text(localStorage["input3"]);
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a nice place to use websockets.

Either pass the whole content through the websocket message or store them in localstorage and send a message to the clients that new content is available.

This way you can also scale it for as many clients you want